# How do I assign a class variable interactively in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, memory

I want to share a variable between class instances. However, the variable itself takes a while to compute.

I am reluctant to put it inside the class definition like so:

```
class MyClass:

    my_var = MyVar().generate_my_var()

    def __init__():
         pass
    
    etc.
```

As it will be taking a while to compute the variable each-time I want to re-load / re-import MyClass in Jupyter.

Is there a way to assign a class variable interactively in Jupyter without altering the class definition?

Can I just do this:

```
import MyClass
my_var = MyVar().generate_my_var()
MyClass.my_var = my_var
```

Or should I create a class method to which I can pass the variable so that the method binds it to the class? If so, what would that class method look like?

I should point out that the reason I want to share the variable between class instances is that I do not want to create unnecessary copies of it (it is a large pandas dataframe). However, maybe my concerns are unwarranted? Would the instances still only contain pointers to it?

If so, what if some of the instances change some of the columns in that dataframe? Does it get copied then, or only those changed columns would get copied? Thanks!

Comment: ```import MyClass
my_var = MyVar().generate_my_var()
MyClass.my_var = my_var``` should work

Comment: All python variables act as references. Unless you *explicitly* make a copy, data will not be copied by simple assignment to a variable/attribute (unless someone goes out of their way to do some metaclass/ descriptor magic to force that). In any case, classes will only be loaded *once* per process, no matter how many import statements load the module.

Comment: *Anyway*, you asked if `Myclass.my_var = my_var` would work... *did you try and see?* (yes, it will work).

Comment: Understood. Thanks! So just to reiterate, there's no difference between a class variable and an instance variable in terms of memory usage (all else being equal)? Also, Do you mind posting your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Nope. A class itself *is* an instance, of its metaclass.

Comment: @nijshar28 The difference is that there's only one class variable per class, but a separate instance variable for each instance.